# My HTML favicon is not working when I use exactly what it should be

Tags: html, brave

My websites favicon is NOT working no matter what I try. I am on Brave browser.
Here is the code for that:

```
<body style="background-color:gray">
  <title>MultiLangCoder Games</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="multilangcoder.repl.co/Logo.ico"/>
</body>
```

I followed every help online, but NOTHING worked!

Comment: It looks like the `href` isn't correct. Missing the `http(s)://`

Comment: is this your icon?  https://multilangcoder.repl.co/Logo.ico

Comment: Yes.  That is my icon.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is already solved, but just for good measures:
The `<title> </title>` and `<link> </link>` tags both go in the `<head> </head>`. This also applies for some other tags as you can see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp).

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Turns out I didn't understand too well what everyone else meant by that.

Answer (score -1):

Commenter is probably right, change the href link to: "https://multilangcoder.repl.co/Logo.ico"
Works in both firefox and chrome for me.